# jQuery scroll to not working

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, scroll

I'm trying to get my site to scroll down when I click on an arrow. It can be viewed here http://www.divisionforty.com/dbarr/

However, for some reason nothing is happening on click. It doesn't work at all. I've tried it on other divs with no better luck.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hopefully someone can help.

Thanks,
Denver

Comment: check `target.length` , quick test on a few links running your code in console returns `0`. Set a breakpoint and step through your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that happens because your `a` tag inside the `#circlediv` is not visually visible (has width and height equal to zero)!

what you must do is to wrap the `#circlediv` with the `a` element, as below:

```
<div class="upper">         
    <a href="#article">
        <div id="circlediv">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: HMM, it still doesn't want to load

Comment: load what? I checked your website again and it worked! am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, could it be the cache?

Answer (score 0):

I checked your DOM elements and there is no example ul or something. 
See this example's DOM element in this example with name [SmoothPageScroll](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/) which has the structure below and you have to make something like this in your site:

```
<div id="page-wrap">

        <h1 id="top">Smooth Page Scrolling</h1>
        ...
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/examples/SmoothPageScroll/#two">Scroll to Section Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#three">Scroll to Section Three</a></li>
        </ul>

        <h1 id="one">Section One</h1>       
        ...
        <h1 id="two">Section Two</h1>        
        ...
        <p><a href="#top">Top</a></p>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your page now and found this out:

Your `<a>` tag is inside the circlediv and its size is 0x0 pixels, so you can't click it.

Try this instead:

```
<a href="#article">
    <div id="circlediv">
    </div>
</a>
```

Secondly, you don't have any element with an `id='article'`, so it doesn't find any element to scroll to.